# Internal Error: Image is a collection image,expecting ADT with Oracle

Tags: oracle, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am trying to call a stored function on an oracle database with spring-jdbc.

This is the stored function I am trying to call:

```
FUNCTION GET_RESOURCE_LIST RETURN RESOURCE_TAB;
```

Next is the definition of resource_tab

```
TYPE RESOURCE_TAB AS TABLE OF TRESOURCE;
```

Next is the definition of tresource

```
TYPE TRESOURCE AS OBJECT(
RESOURCE_ID NUMBER(10,0),
RESOURCE_NAME VARCHAR2(100)
)
```

The calling code

```
final SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(idmJdbcTemplate).withFunctionName("get_resource_list").declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter(
        "RETURN", OracleTypes.STRUCT,
        "RESOURCE_TAB",
        new SqlReturnType() {

          @Override
          public Object getTypeValue(CallableStatement cs, int paramIndex, int sqlType, String typeName) throws SQLException {
            final Struct s = (Struct)cs.getObject(paramIndex);
            final Object[] attr = s.getAttributes();
            return attr[1];
          }             
        }));

call.compile();
final Collection<String> resources = call.executeFunction(Collection.class);
```

Last is the stack trace that I am receiving:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{? = call WVUID.IDM_REPO_MANUAL.GET_RESOURCE_LIST()}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17001]; Internal Error: Image is a collection image,expecting ADT; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Internal Error: Image is a collection image,expecting ADT
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:969)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1003)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: java.sql.SQLException: Internal Error: Image is a collection image,expecting ADT
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:271)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$5.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1015)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$5.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:953)
    ... 62 more
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle?  Which version of the JDBC driver?

Comment: Oracle 11G and the Drivers on Weblogic 10.3.2.0 which I would guess is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem, and I spent a day to fix it.
Thinking about error "Image is a collection image", instead of

`OracleTypes.STRUCT` it must be `OracleTypes.ARRAY`.

About your getTypeValue(...) method I can't say is it right or not, but I will show how parse the resultset (maybe it is and other way, please write it):

```
@Override
public Object getTypeValue(CallableStatement cs, int paramIndex,
        int sqlType, String typeName) throws SQLException {

    ARRAY struct = (ARRAY) cs.getObject(paramIndex);

    ResultSet rs = struct.getResultSet();

    while (rs.next()) {
        Object rowIndex = rs.getObject(1);
        oracle.sql.STRUCT row = (oracle.sql.STRUCT) rs.getObject(2);
        if (row != null) {
            Object[] cols = row.getAttributes();
            System.out.print(rowIndex + ": ");
            for (Object col : cols) {
                System.out.print(col + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    return "construct your data structure above and return here";
}
```

the another way is

```
    @Override
public Object getTypeValue(CallableStatement cs, int paramIndex,
        int sqlType, String typeName) throws SQLException {

    ARRAY array = (ARRAY) cs.getObject(paramIndex);

    Object[] rows = (Object[])array.getArray();

    for(Object row : rows){
        Object[] cols = ((oracle.sql.STRUCT)row).getAttributes();
        for (Object col : cols) {
            System.out.print(col + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

    return "construct your data structure above and return here";
}
```

Comment: I am no longer working at the place where I was trying to make the code work, so I can't verify this answer, but it seems like the most likely solution.

Comment: I have the same problem and it is not the wrong object type: System.out.println(cs.getObject(paramIndex) gives me oracle.sql.STRUCT@<hash>.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the declaration of the output parameter

```
final SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(idmJdbcTemplate).withFunctionName("get_resource_list").declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter(
    "RETURN", OracleTypes.STRUCT,
    "RESOURCE_TAB",
    new SqlReturnType() <etc>
```

The return type (`TYPE RESOURCE_TAB AS TABLE OF TRESOURCE`) is not a `OracleTypes.STRUCT` (that is reserved for Object Types) but an `OracleTypes.ARRAY`.